# Unable to decrypted Base64 encoded AES-256-CBC encrypted string in iOS, always results in nil string

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography

I am retrieving encrypted data from server, which the encryption is done with the following code in PHP:

```
$password = '1234567890123456';

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_CAST_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
$encryptedString = openssl_encrypt('I am a testing string', "AES-256-CBC", $password, 0, $iv);

$json['encrypted_feed'] = base64_encode($iv . $encryptedString);
$json['iv'] = base64_encode($iv);

echo json_encode($json);
```

Then after retrieving the data from server in the following JSON object:

```
{
    "encrypted_string":"IRcqgAMvXlEm17wUwrwwmE5NRmVrbUlpSEp4NUpta2JNdmMrdzhFOVVzRFR4bkVXUjluMVJwaXNYYTA9",
    "iv":"IRcqgAMvXlEm17wUwrwwmA=="
}
```

Then in my iOS application, I tried to decrypted it with various means:

**1. Using the utilities in the [CommonCrypto tools here](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit):**

** `responseObject` is a dictionary

```
NSString *password = @"1234567890123456";
NSData *pwData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *base64FeedStr = [responseObject objectForKey:@"encrypted_feed"];
NSString *base64IVStr = [responseObject objectForKey:@"iv"];

NSData *base64FeedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:b64FeedStr options:0];
NSData *base64IVData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64IVStr options:0];

NSData *decryptedFeedData = [b64FeedData decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES key:password initializationVector:b64IVData options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:nil];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedFeedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Following with this, I've also tried to chop away the IV data attached at the beginning and then follow with the decrypting sequence above, but the result remains the same.

**2. With the [BBAES toos here](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBAES)**

```
// According to the header:
// @param iv: the IV used to encrypt the data or nil if the encryption uses the `BBAESEncryptionOptionsIncludeIV` parameter
// i.e. the IV is saved along with the ciphertext (the IV is stored as the first block of the encrypted data).

// I also tried passing the IV into it but no luck.
NSData *resultData = [BBAES decryptedDataFromString:b64FeedStr IV:nil key:pwData];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I've also tried to use `AES-128` in php but the result remains the same, i.e. `nil` in the resulting NSString.

I only have a very shallow understanding of Cryptography. After all these tweaking with the same result, I am feeling frustrated without ideas about which part has gone wrong.

If there is any insights regarding how could I decrypt and retrieve the original string I would be very grateful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

1. `MCRYPT_CAST_256` specifies the deprecated Cast encryption algorithm, not AES.
2. Do not use Cast, use AES
3. AES is `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` (mcrypt does not make things clear).
4. An IV was used, during encryption and prepended to the encrypted data. not must be used on decryption. Base64 decode, split the IV and encrypted data.
5. It is best to use a complete cross platform library such as [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor). It is hard to get encryption correct and secure from cryptographic primitives.